# Getting ValueError on Prediction after PCA and K-Means

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I first applied PCA to my dataset as a dimension reduction method. then K means clustering has been performed on the PCA dataset.

As the final step of my project, I need to predict the cluster of new data.

However, when i try to do PCA transformation on new data, the following error occurred,

```
ValueError: n_components=2 must be between 0 and min(n_samples, n_features)=1 with svd_solver='full'
```

I get that we need more records to perform the PCA on new data. But, as for my objective of the project, i get only one record at a time.

**What is the right procedure for this kind of analysis apart from this**
or
**What is the solution for this**

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to SO, you should post a working [MRE], so we see what you have tried/done so far and so we can reproduce and help better.

Comment: My question in brief is, how to apply PCA on one data point. I am getting above while applying x = [[ ]] array on pca.fit_transform

Comment: You are fitting pca on each test data. Instead you should fit on train data and use transform/predict for test data

Comment: first bug according to the error message :  n_components=2 is wrong it should be between 0 and 1 ... when using 

then look at examples given in the answer bellow, and come back and  post full piece of code, so we see what your are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc here : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html

n_components mut be between 0. and 1. and is a percentage when using svd_solver

If you need you have a full PCA exemple here : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-datasets-plot-iris-dataset-py

and many otherones at the bottow of the page : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html